# How to effect table cells on resizing of a event div

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a calendar and now making events system by clicking on each cell, by clicking on each cell I am creating a resize and drag and drop able div, by dropping div into another cell makes the effect on that cell. In my case I am just changing the background color of drop able cell. Now the problem is on resizing the div I am not able to make effect on the new cells.

For example I click on cell of 9, by adding some information in popup I create an event for that day but I want to increase that event from 9 to 11 by just resizing the div.

Just like [This full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). How can I make effect on the new cells on resizing the div?

My calendar image

[image]

I am strictly not allowed to use jQuery, just pure javascript.

**JS**

```
        calendar.prototype.drag = function (ev){        
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        this.dragStartPoint = document.getElementById(ev.target.id).parentElement;
        }

    calendar.prototype.drop = function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var getElem = document.getElementById(data);
        ev.target.appendChild(getElem);
        ev.target.style.backgroundColor = "darkgray";

        if ((this.dragStartPoint.children.length) < 1) {
            this.dragStartPoint.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        }
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.eventDragDiv{    
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 125px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

include this  eventLimit: false in your js. then based on the events in the calender it resizes itself.